# Select Query for Days of the Week

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

When using the following query to return days of the week I'd like to only show a specific day (Monday, for example) and count the number of times 'Monday' is returned.

```
     SELECT
      w.[Id]
    , w.[Name]
    , [Status]
    , [InitiatorPersonAliasId]
    , p.[FirstName]
    , p.[LastName]
    , ( SELECT TOP 1 [Value]
        FROM [AttributeValue] av
        INNER JOIN [Attribute] a ON a.[Id] = av.[AttributeId] 
        AND a.[EntityTypeId] = 113 
        AND a.[EntityTypeQualifierColumn] = 'WorkflowTypeId' 
        AND a.[EntityTypeQualifierValue] = w.[WorkflowTypeId]
        WHERE [EntityId] = w.[Id] 
        AND a.[Key] = 'DayOfTheWeek'
      ) AS [Day]
    , (SELECT TOP 1 [Value]
        FROM [AttributeValue] av
        INNER JOIN [Attribute] a ON a.[Id] = av.[AttributeId] 
        AND a.[EntityTypeId] = 113 
        AND a.[EntityTypeQualifierColumn] = 'WorkflowTypeId' 
        AND a.[EntityTypeQualifierValue] = w.[WorkflowTypeId]
        WHERE [EntityId] = w.[Id] 
        AND a.[Key] = 'Time'
      ) AS [Time]
FROM
[Workflow] w
INNER JOIN [PersonAlias] pa ON pa.Id = w.[InitiatorPersonAliasId]
INNER JOIN [Person] p ON p.[Id] = pa.[PersonId] 
WHERE w.[WorkflowTypeId] = 1032
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Groupy by in combination with Count is probably what you are looking for, go check on Google for those key words! if you have any problems, let us know

Comment: @Belairit . . . One could probably guess that there is a date column somewhere in there.  Couldn't one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write as:

```
;With cte_DayCount as
(
        SELECT av.[Value] as DayCount,w.[Id]  AS Id
        FROM [AttributeValue] av
        INNER JOIN [Workflow] w ON av.[EntityId] = w.[Id] 
        INNER JOIN [Attribute] a ON a.[Id] = av.[AttributeId]         
        AND a.[EntityTypeId] = 113 
        AND a.[EntityTypeQualifierColumn] = 'WorkflowTypeId' 
        AND a.[EntityTypeQualifierValue] = w.[WorkflowTypeId]
        AND a.[Key] = 'DayOfTheWeek'
        WHERE [Value] Like '%Monday%' -- Add day value here
        GROUP BY w.[Id], av.Value 
)                
SELECT COUNT(dc.DayCount) AS Total

FROM
[Workflow] w
INNER JOIN [PersonAlias] pa ON pa.Id = w.[InitiatorPersonAliasId]
INNER JOIN [Person] p ON p.[Id] = pa.[PersonId] 
INNER JOIN cte_DayCount dc ON DC.Id = w.[Id]
WHERE w.[WorkflowTypeId] = 1032
```

Comment: For some reason this returns: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3  Incorrect syntax near ','.